# Prevent 404 to load from SavedRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a

```java
public class OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler
```

with method

```java
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        User user = processOidcUser((DefaultOidcUser) authentication.getPrincipal());
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
```

and it works fine. I can login either with Username and Password or with OAuth2.

But for some reason, in both options, there seems to be a

```java
SavedRequest savedRequest = this.requestCache.getRequest(request, response);
```

which has a bug: If there is an element on the frontpage that cannot be loaded, the SavedRequest does not forward to the URL where it should with "?continue", but instead it forwards to the URL which returned 404.

I can only avoid this by not having dead links anywhere, but as this can happen from time to time, it is annoying that this happens even after I specified setDefaultTargetUrl("/"); it still forwards to the dead link.

I also tried to check this link in SavedRequest for status code, but apparently, Spring resolves the 404 internally and returns 200 on the 404 page.